# Focus on address bar in Safari

Tags: macos, safari

A few days ago i noticed, that in new tab cursor doesn't set on address/search bar. Now I use <kbd>⌘+L</kbd> combination to quickly switch, but it isn't comfortably for long time use.

Reflecting on the causes of such behavior , I found that the cursor stands on a search tab in the **private tab**.

What i tried to do to fix it:

1. Set in general preferences parameter *Open new tabs/windows with*  Empty page
2. Turn off all extensions

I have OSX 10.11.5 with Safari 9.1.1 *(and also i have the same problem on Safari Technology Preview 9.1.1)*

---

### Example:

Open new window [image]

Press combination <kbd>cmd+T</kbd>

[image]

But when I do same actions in private window cursor has already focused on address bar.
[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear - are you saying when you open a new tab you would like it to immediately focus on the address bar?

Comment: @TimMalone Yes. I always open a new tab by cmd+T  and start typing query or name of site. But now between this two process necessary use cmd+L. In private tab works well without additional actions. Maybe I knocked out some important settings or collied with issue in safari or osx.

Comment: Have you tried going to the Safari menu? Menu Bar > History > Clear History... > Select 'Clear all history' > Clear history. Be sure to make a backup of your computer if you want to save _any_ of your Safari files.

Comment: @Brick Yeah, but same result. I tried to install  Safari Technology Preview and again I have the same result. I think it's little specific bug that difficult to repeat and catch. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Safari/Preferences/Search and uncheck Include Safari Suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was waiting when bug comes again, and your solution is work. But i can't understand why this bug is shows itself randomly when this settings is checked.

Answer (score 2):

I think I might have a soft solution.

1. Exit from full screen
2. Enter full screen again

This seems to fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

There was no updates installed for Safari or for OS X, but now tabs opens with focused address bar.  I have cleared Safari's history and cookies, but it does not help at that time. I think it just elusive bug, because now I can't repeat it. I have only one decision - wait when OS X remove this bug itself.

Comment: Did you completely close Safari (⌘+Q) before the problem resolved itself? When you close your last tab, Safari stays open, just without a window. Quitting the app often resolves issues such as that one.

Comment: I always use <kbd>⌘+Q</kbd> when want to close Safari. It's funny, but after  yesterday's answer I have met three times this bug. Still searching what app or action leads to this bug. Thanks for your comment @Phong

Answer (score 1):

I think I might know what is going on. I had the same issue and I believe it was because I set the default home page in safari to Google. When I opened the browser (or a new tab) it switched the focus to the Google Homepage Search Box.

Under "Preferences / General / ..." changing the settings "New windows open with" and "New tabs open with" to something other than a website page fixed the issue for me and now any time I open a new browser window or tab the focus is set to the Safari Search bar.